# Vue js - How can i show API request in terminal of vs code?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, terminal

How can i show API request in terminal of vs code?
So i'm using vs code and i would like to my API response in terminal.
for example

```
GET -> API URL -> Status code
```

for each page that i enter.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically if you wanna print the response in your terminal then you need to something like

```
axios().then(resp => console.log(resp));
```

If you wanna test your api's from within VSCode then do
Check this out a VSCode extension
https://www.thunderclient.io

Comment: I would like to print all the page responses.

Comment: I don't want to see them in console terminal when i'm doing inspect, I would like to see them only in vs code terminal

Comment: no that's not possible as of now...there are no extensions for this as well.

Comment: I think it's like proxy for angular

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if their is anyway possible for you to fetch data from API on the terminal of VScode. Unless you can create your won Vs Code plugin to handle on the same.

Check out this article, it will help you with that.
https://blog.bitsrc.io/vs-codes-rest-client-plugin-is-all-you-need-to-make-api-calls-e9e95fcfd85a